# Only one letter is missing in the first name

Tags: air-travel, saudi-airlines

My mother name is Firdous Bano and mistakenly typed Fidous Bano while I made online booking with Saudi Airlines. Rest of the information is correct. While this be a problem?

Comment: Call them now and get it corrected. Right after the booking, they are probably accepting the typo and change it. Don't wait until check-in.